# Dojo v1.6 dojo.attr() Returning NULL

Tags: javascript, dojo, attr

I am writing a small script that validates a form.

The code below...

```
alert( dojo.query(dojo.query(requiredItem).parent('form')).children('.' + settings['confirmEmailClass']) );
```

...returns an input element as expected, however, when I try to get an attribute using it as the node that I am working on, it always returns NULL...

```
alert( dojo.attr( dojo.query(dojo.query(requiredItem).parent('form')).children('.' + settings['confirmEmailClass']), 'value') );
```

I am certain that the attribute that I am checking for exists. I am used to working with jQuery, so some of my chaining may be long winded, any tips would help.

NOTE: I am limited to using Dojo v1.6 for this project.

Thanks.

EDIT: It seams that dojo.attr() returns an array, (I guess because I'm querying by class?) and if I do...

```
alert( dojo.attr( dojo.query(dojo.query(requiredItem).parent('form')).children('.' + settings['confirmEmailClass'])[0], 'value') );
```

...I get what I am looking for. Is there a better way I should be checking for an attribute by class?

Comment: Can you break this out into variables with names that have semantic meaning? That one-liner is very hard to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dojo.attr is not returning an array but dojo.query always does.
Changing code to this should help:

```
alert( dojo.attr( dojo.query(dojo.query(requiredItem)[0].parent('form'))[0].children('.' + settings['confirmEmailClass'])[0], 'value') );
```